# s3cmd tool on Windows server with progress support

Tags: python, windows, progress-bar, progress, s3cmd

As the title suggests, I am using the s3cmd tool to upload/download files on Amazon.
However I have to use Windows Server and bring in some sort of progress reporting. 
The problem is that on windows, s3cmd gives me the following error:

`ERROR: Option --progress is not yet supported on MS Windows platform. Assuming -
-no-progress.`

Now, I need this --progress option.
Are there any workarounds for that? Or maybe some other tool?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I have found a decent workaround to that:

Just navigate to `C:\Python27\Scripts\s3cmd` and comment out lines 1837-1845.
This way we can essentially skip a windows check and print progress on the cmd.
However, since it works normally, I have no clue why the authors put it there in the first place.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

In today's version one has to comment out lines 1816 to 1822.
This is the part that you have to comment out in the file (in case in future versions the line numbers change again):

```
## Unsupported features on Win32 platform
```

## if os.name == "nt":

## if cfg.preserve_attrs:

## error(u"Option --preserve is not yet supported on MS Windows platform. Assuming --no-preserve.")

## cfg.preserve_attrs = False

## if cfg.progress_meter:

## error(u"Option --progress is not yet supported on MS Windows platform. Assuming --no-progress.")

## cfg.progress_meter = False